# Fancontrol on asus z97 board

Tags: asus, fan, temperature, fancontrol

I have been reading for last couple of days about fancontrol and I'm not able to get it to work. I've tried with lm-sensors and pwmconfig and bunch of another shenanigans but I'm stuck at: "no pwm capable devices".
I have windows as side system and on windows I'm controlling motherboard fans with asus AI suite, GPU with msi burner and CPU fans (corsair h80i) with corsair link. Can someone point me in the right direction at least to get these motherboard fans to work.
sensors output:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +105.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +33.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +32.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

asus-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
cpu_fan:        0 RPM
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you confirm what sensor chip your MB uses?  It should be a Novatron chip located near the Battery. Once you identify the number (mine is a 6791), then you can check the /etc/sensors3.conf file to make sure there is an entry for that chip. Post your findings here and I'll try to help further.

Comment: Hi, I have switched on archlinux in the meantime but still have the same problem. It's same as yours although, I have an d on the end so it's 6791d. and there is an entry for nct6791-* in sensors3.conf:  label in0 "Vcore"
<code>
    label in2 "AVCC"
    label in3 "+3.3V"
    label in7 "3VSB"
    label in8 "Vbat"

    set in2_min  3.3 * 0.90
    set in2_max  3.3 * 1.10
    set in3_min  3.3 * 0.90
    set in3_max  3.3 * 1.10
    set in7_min  3.3 * 0.90
    set in7_max  3.3 * 1.10
    set in8_min  3.0 * 0.90
    set in8_max  3.3 * 1.10
</code>